# Use a new layout in each tab?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

After setting up a tab host I was wondering if it is possible to have a new layout in each of the tabs that are set up  instead of defining all the objects within the same xml file.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Try from here http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    TabSpec p = tabHost.newTabSpec("name");

    p.setIndicator("name");
    Intent pIntent = new Intent(this, Name.class);
    p.setContent(pIntent);

    TabSpec s = tabHost.newTabSpec("name1");
    s.setIndicator("name1");
    Intent sIntent = new Intent(this, Name1.class);
    s.setContent(sIntent);

    TabSpec v = tabHost.newTabSpec("name2");
    v.setIndicator("name2");
    Intent vIntent = new Intent(this, Name2.class);
    v.setContent(vIntent);

    tabHost.addTab(p);
    tabHost.addTab(s);
    tabHost.addTab(v);
```

Here is the link to the tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/